# Alias conversions

Tags: go, casting

I have `struct AccessToken` as a part of external library and I use that library in my own. I'd like to return a value of this type but I do not see any reasons why my internal implementation should be visible from outside. Type alias looks great for this.

```
type AccessToken oauth.AccessToken
```

But I'm getting an error when trying to do next:

```
func Auth(key string, secret string) *AccessToken {
...
    var token oauth.AccessToken = AuthorizeToken(...)
    return AccessToken(*token)
}
```

Error:

```
cannot use AccessToken(*accessToken) (type AccessToken) as type *AccessToken in return argument
```

It's clear that I can just copy structures field by fiend. But is there any way to use aliases?

Comment: "I'm getting an error." What error?

Comment: Just to be clear on the terminology, the only *aliases* in Go are `byte` for `uint8` and `rune` for `int32`. When you define a new type, it's a *new type*.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

<s>I don't know what error you are getting, but</s> this expression is wrong:

```
func Auth(key string, secret string) *AccessToken {
...
    var token oauth.AccessToken = AuthorizeToken(...)
    return AccessToken(*token)
}
```

it's saying "take the pointer-value of `token` (which is not a pointer at all, meaning it's a syntax error), cast that as `AccessToken` and return it". But the function returns a **pointer to** AccessToken, not a value, so this is invalid.

If you are returning a pointer to your `AccessToken` type, the code should be more along the lines of:

```
func Auth(key string, secret string) *AccessToken {
...
    token := AccessToken(AuthorizeToken(...))
    return &token
}
```